# Why are there metal links between the discs of an overhead line insulators?

Tags: power, transmission-line, insulator

[image]

They form interlink capacitance and reduce the string efficiency. A lot of other non metallic strong materials can be used instead.

Comment: Those are lightning arrestors, apparently.

Comment: Metals are strong, cheap, and have a long life.

Comment: Maybe you can point out precisely in your picture the items you refer to?

Comment: The text from Wikipedia for this picture:  *Suspension insulator - For voltages greater than 33 kV, it is a usual practice to use suspension type insulators, consisting of a number of glass or porcelain discs connected in series by metal links in the form of a string. The conductor is suspended at the bottom end of this string while the top end is secured to the cross-arm of the tower. The number of disc units used depends on the voltage.*

Comment: Well I'm not expert in high voltage AC distribution networks. But are you sure what you say is actually correct?

Answer (score 2):

The insulator string is under tension.

Ceramics are not particularly good at tension strength, particularly when outside and moving around.

The vertical part of the stack is alternating metal tension links, where metal works well, and ceramic insulating compressive sections.

[image: image of insulator section]
As to capacitance: although I haven’t done a specific calculation, I don’t believe there’s a significant source of loss there. The reactance of large transmission lines is carefully controlled, and the insulators are part of that engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Transmission line insulators have to meet a large number of requirements. They need to withstand the voltage, obviously, but they also need to deal with the static and dynamic loads associated with holding up the wire. Furthermore, they need to do this for a long time while exposed to a lot of environmental stress, such as temperature extremes, exposure to UV from sunlight, mechanical impact from hail, accumulation of surface contaminants, etc.

Given the vast numbers of these that are installed around the world, I think it's safe to assume that the engineers have done their homework and determined that what you see is the most **cost-effective** solution.

Comment: +1, but isn't there a risk that metal provide path for leakage current causes some energy loss ?

Comment: @user215805: That's just one of the factors that goes into the calculation of overall cost-effectiveness,

Answer (score 1):

Why is there metal? because the ceramic or glass is rigid, and will break under lateral/wind loads. The various pieces of metal form pieces of a long flexible chain, each metallic interface being one link of the flexible chain.

–